# How does yarn work when it encounters ^ (caret) with a lock file?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

How does yarn work when it encounter a `^` (caret) in package.json dependencies?

Let's say I have react: `^16.0.0` and when I yarn install, it will create a lock on that version (`16.0.0`).

Now sometime later when react `16.1.0` is released, and I yarn install again with the lock file, will yarn upgrade it to that version or follow what is in the lock file which is `16.0.0`?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe not unless someone does `yarn upgrade`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`yarn install` will install the exact version in the lockfile. That's the great benefit of a lockfile, everyone working on your project gets the exact same version of the package regardless of when the do yarn install. (e.g. I do yarn install today, when 16.0.0 is the current version, but you do yarn install tomorrow when 16.1.0 is the current version. We'll still both get 16.0.0 because that's what our lockfile says we should get. Our development environments are exactly the same, which is what we want. Likewise if we deploy in 2 weeks when 16.2.0 is the current version, 16.0.0 will get deployed; thus our dev and prod environments are exactly the same, too)

If 16.1.0 is released and you want to update your project to use it, use `yarn upgrade`. Note that you can upgrade *all* of your packages, or just one specific package, as well as update to the latest version of a package or a specific version of a package. https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

#### Version Control Your package.json and yarn.lock

By adding these two files to version control, you'll easily be able to revert your project to a specific point in time in regards to your packages.

#### Edit in 2024 -- Read the Question, and Read the Other Answer**

OPs question was how **yarn** behaves with a caret **and** a lock file:

> will yarn upgrade it to that version or follow what is in the lock file which is 16.0.0?

**Here's the important concept**: yarn behaves *very* differently if you are using a lock file, than if you are *not* using a lock file.

If you're wondering what a caret means *without* a lock file, read the other answer by thecaveman (excepting his comment that this answer here is wrong...it is not). But know that if you are using a **lock file**, like OP asked, you need to read this answer above to understand how yarn behaves.

Comment: Hi does your answer apply to a specification of just  "16.0.0"? (that is, no tilde ~ or caret ~).  I saw this description about tilde and caret: So if you see ~1.0.2 it means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest patch version such as 1.0.4. If you see ^1.0.2 it means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest minor or patch version such as 1.1.0. (c.f. https://michaelsoolee.com/npm-package-tilde-caret/)

Comment: @leeyuiwah with just "16.0.0" you are saying "install exactly version 16.0.0"  You will not get any updates whatsoever, the version in your project will be locked to 16.0.0

Comment: The OP specifically asked about ^, this answer is therefore confusing

Comment: @davkutalek no, OP specifically asked how **yarn** behaves with a caret **and** a lock file. Here is the quoted question: "How does yarn work when it encounter a ^...will yarn upgrade it to that version or follow what is in the lock file which is 16.0.0?"

Comment: I could have been clearer: when the OP says "Let's say I have react: ^16.0.0 and when I yarn install, it will create a lock on that version (16.0.0)." that isn't true if the latest is higher - yarn will lock the latest version below 17. Ppl looking for this question just might need more clarity is all

Comment: @davkutalek correct -- folks coming here, read the question in it's entirety carefully. OP asked a very specific question about yarn, caret, and lock file. They did **not** ask what happens when you run `yarn install` the very first time.

Answer (score 8):

The selected answer is wrong.

caret means following

> ^3.1.4 will allow a version range from >=3.1.4 <4.0.0

Comment: Hey caveman, how is the selected answer wrong? Your answer isn't answering the question, consider commenting instead or provide more info

Comment: @dube the question is how yarn handles `^`, not what a lockfile does

Comment: @neaumusic Err yes, what yarn does when a lockfile is present _is_ the question, While caveman ignored it and explained what the caret means. But the asker likely knows what the caret means, thus the question.

Comment: @dube no the question is `how does yarn work when it encounters ^ (caret)?`

Comment: @neaumusic `... when ^x is specified and x.y is in the lockfile`, which is answered correctly below, while this response here does not answer at all. Anyway caveman didn't bother to extend his answer, case closed.

Comment: @dube the problem is the question not the answer, anyone coming from a search engine like google or stackoverflow will be misled that the question is asking about a lockfile

Comment: Let's agree that the first answer could have included the range, but it is not wrong and includes important context, that needs to be know too - especially by noobs. The 2nd however claims the first is wrong (it's not) and pastes a range without anything. I would consider that low quality. And lastly, I likely landed here because I wanted to know how it works (the title) not what caret means. Google shows me a different question for "what does caret in yarn it mean". And one could crosslink that question, if you think it's a problem

Comment: As an outsider who has come from Google looking for an answer, this is the response that i was looking for